# Как правильно унаследовать класс?

Tags: наследование, классы, java

Есть класс для работы с большими целыми знаковыми числами.

```
 public class BigNum 
{
    static int base = 100;
    static int LenNum=3000;
    int num[];

    //Конструкторы
    //выделение памяти
    BigNum() {
        num = new int [LenNum];
    }
    //перевод числа в base-ичную систему
    BigNum(int x) {
        this();
        int i=LenNum-1;
        while (x>0)
        {
            num[i]=x%base;
            x/=base;
            i--;            
        }
    }
    //конструктор копирования
    BigNum(BigNum x) {
        this();
        int i=LenNum;
        while (i>=0) {
            num[i]=x.num[i];
            i--;
        }
    }
    //Функция копирования 
    void copy (BigNum x) {
        for (int i = 0; i<LenNum; i++)
            num[i]=x.num[i];
    }

    //функция сложения
    void add(BigNum x) {
        int ost=0;
        int i=LenNum-1;
        for (;i>=0; i--) {
            num[i]+=x.num[i]+ost;
            ost=num[i]/base;
            num[i]%=base;
        }

    }

    //функция для сравнения чисел
    public boolean a_b(BigNum x) {
        int i=0;

        while (i<LenNum && num[i]==x.num[i])
            i++;

        if (i==LenNum || num[i]>=x.num[i])
            return false;
        else
            return true;
        }

    //вычитание
    void sub(BigNum x) {
        int ost=0;
        for (int i=LenNum-1; i>=0; i--) {
            num[i]=(num[i] - x.num[i]+ost);
            if (num[i]<0) 
            {
                ost=-1;
                num[i]+=base;
            }
            else
                ost=0;
        }
    }

    //Функция умножения
    void mul(BigNum x) {
        BigNum rez=new BigNum();
        int i, j=LenNum-1;
        int lim_j=0, lim_i=0;
        int y; int ost;
        while (x.num[j]<=0)//находим нули для пропуска
            j--;
        while (x.num[lim_j]==0)//находим начало числа
            lim_j++;
        while (num[lim_i]==0)
            lim_i++;
        //начинаем с числа после нулей, до начала числа соответственно
        for (; j>=lim_j; j--) {
            y=j; ost=0;
            BigNum mas =new BigNum();
            //с конца второго числа до его начала
            for (i=LenNum-1; i>=lim_i; i--) {
                mas.num[y]=num[i]*x.num[j]+ost;//умножаем числа в заданных местах
                ost=mas.num[y]/base;//если остаток больше С.С. переводим его в нашу С.С.
                mas.num[y]%=base;
                y--;
            }
            //Добавление остатка в следующие ячейки, при его наличии
            while (ost>0) {             
                mas.num[y]=ost%base;
                ost/=base;
                y--;
            }           
            rez.add(mas);           
        }       
        this.copy(rez);     
    }

    //Деление целочисленное
    void div(BigNum x) {
        BigNum rez = new BigNum(); //результат 
        BigNum one = new BigNum(1); //
        while (!(this.a_b(x))) //пока первое число не станет меньше второго
        {
            this.sub(x); //отнимаем
            rez.add(one); //прибавляем для результата
        }
        x.copy(this);
        this.copy(rez); //копируем в num
    }
    // Печать числа строкой
    static void pr(BigNum x) {
        System.out.println(x.inString());
    }
    //перевод массива в строку
    public String inString() {
        int i=0;
        String str = "";
        while (num[i]==0)
            i++;
        for (; i<LenNum; i++){
            str+=num[i];
            str+='`';
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Нужно создать подкласс для работы с большими числами с плавающей точкой.
Пытался унаследовать его и заменить некоторые методы, но глухо, не знаю, что уже сделать.

Comment: @factura122, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

А в чем, собственно, проблема с наследованием? Судя по условию задачи, наследование неизбежно.

И, кстати, правильнее было бы переименовать метод inString() в toString(). Тогда вывод строкового представления объекта будет выполняться следующим образом:

```
System.out.println(BigNum x);
```